# why does is.null return false for a non-existent list element?

Tags: r, null

I am trying to test if a list contains an object ([github source](https://raw.github.com/PecanProject/pecan/073235d9117faf8719038e095ba589bdaca1e402/settings/R/read.settings.R)). This `is.null` function has worked so far except in the case where I am testing an item with a name that is a partial match to a non-nul item.

```
x <- list(ab = 1)

is.null(x$ab)
[1] FALSE     ## expected
is.null(x$b)
[1] TRUE      ## expected
is.null(x$c)     
[1] TRUE      ## expected
is.null(x$a)
[1] FALSE     ## unexpected
```

Is this expected behavior for the `is.null` function? I don't see any indication in the documentation.

Would it be better to use the `exists` function, or some other approach? (I haven't used `exists` because it won't work in a loop like `for(i in 'a') is.null(x[[i]])`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

look at `x$a`.  This returns `1` due to partial name matching.  So `is.null(x$a)` is `FALSE` since R matches `a` with `ab`.  If you use `[[` notation, you'll get the expected result: `is.null(x[['a']])`.

Comment: got it. as explained in comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16630087/199217