# What is exact difference between adressing column by $mycol, [[mycol]] and [, mycol, with=FALSE]?

Tags: r, data.table

After reading `data.table` FAQ (section 1.5), I had an impression that all three ways of addressing the column are more or less equivalent. But at least the output of `[, mycol, with=FALSE]` is quite different from `$mycol` and `[[mycol]]`:

```
dt1 <- fread(
  " id,colA,colB
   id1,3,xxx
   id2,0,zzz
   id3,NA,yyy
   id4,0,aaa
     ")

dt1$colA <- factor(dt1$colA)

myvar="colA"

dt1$colA
# [1] 3    0    <NA> 0   
# Levels: 0 3

dt1[[myvar]]
# [1] 3    0    <NA> 0   
# Levels: 0 3

dt1[, myvar, with=FALSE]
# colA
# 1:    3
# 2:    0
# 3:   NA
# 4:    0
```

So, what is exact difference between those three approaches? Can I assume that `$mycol` and `[[mycol]]` are always identical? Why `[, mycol, with=FALSE]` "loses" factors?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part of your question, the difference between `$` and `[[`, has been covered before in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369025/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-dfx-and-dfx/4642176#4642176):

> Indexing by `[` is similar to atomic vectors and selects a list of the
>   specified element(s).
>
> Both `[[` and `$` select a single element of the list. The main
>   difference is that `$` does not allow computed indices, whereas `[[`
>   does. `x$name` is equivalent to `x[["name", exact = FALSE]]`. Also,
>   the partial matching behavior of `[[` can be controlled using the
>   `exact` argument.

The notation `dt1[, ..myvar]` in `data.table` produces a data table with the columns evaluated in `myvar`. The result is a one-column data table, and the class of that column is `factor`.

The data frame equivalent would be: `as.data.frame(dt1)[, myvar, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: ah, I missed that the last form also gives `factor`. Thanks a lot for explaining!